# Free space information about FS on AIX system

Tags: lvm, aix

I am looking for a faster way to know how much space my filesystem on an AIX system has available to grow into.
Currently, I am using:

```
lsvg -o | lsvg -i -l
savevg:
LV NAME             TYPE       LPs     PPs     PVs  LV STATE      MOUNT POINT
logsave             jfs2log    1       1       1    open/syncd    N/A
rmanlvp             jfs2       282     282     1    open/syncd    /oradata/rman
opcon               jfs2       4       4       1    open/syncd    /opt/OpCon
```

That way, I know that my **FS /opt/OpCon** is under the **VG savevg**
Then :

```
lsvg savevg
VOLUME GROUP:       savevg                   VG IDENTIFIER:  00f612c600004c000000014c2c91c0fb
VG STATE:           active                   PP SIZE:        1024 megabyte(s)
VG PERMISSION:      read/write               TOTAL PPs:      699 (715776 megabytes)
MAX LVs:            256                      FREE PPs:       217 (222208 megabytes)
```

Is there any way to know directly how much space is available for the filesystem to grow into?

Comment: You're concerned only with the remaining free space in the VG, and not with any free space remaining in the FS?

Comment: About the free space remaining on FS, df can always help me. So only concerned with the remain free space in the VG but only with filling out the FS as an argument.

If i try :
`chfs -a size=+5G /opt/OpCon`

I want to know if there's free space available for this FS.
Maybe it's only possible via a script ?

Thanks for your answer and sorry about with the bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script below does some sanity-checking of the input (expecting exactly one filesystem, and it should exist), then discovers the desired information in steps:

1. given the filesystem, extract the LV from `lsfs`
2. with the LV, extract the VG from `lslv`
3. with the VG, extract the free space from `lsvg`

Here's the script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# input: a filesystem
# output: free MB in the containing VG

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]
then
  printf "Usage: %s [ fs ]\n" "$0" >&2
  exit 1
fi

if ! /usr/sbin/lsfs -c "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1
then
  printf "Error: filesystem %s not found\n" "$1" >&2
  exit 2
fi

lv=$(/usr/sbin/lsfs -c "$1" |
        awk -F: 'NR == 2 {
                           split($2, fields, "/");
                           print fields[3]
                         }')
vg=$(LANG=C lslv "$lv" 2>/dev/null | awk '/VOLUME GROUP/ { print $6 }')
copies=$(LANG=C lslv "$lv" 2>/dev/null | awk '/^COPIES:/ {print $2}')
mb=$(LANG=C /usr/sbin/lsvg "$vg" |
  awk -F: '/FREE PP/ {match($3, /\([[:digit:]]*/); print substr($3, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1)}')
printf "%d Mb available\n" "$((mb / copies))"
```

To describe some sections of the code that may not be obvious:

- the `awk` script for `lsfs` splits the output on colons and only operates on line 2 (since line 1 is a header). The value in field 2 is something like `/dev/opcon`, so we split it into the `fields` array based on forward-slashes. Element one is empty (nothing before the first `/`), element two is `dev`, and element three is `opcon`, the LV name we want.
- the `awk` script for `lsvg` picks out the free-space line; the third colon-delimited field is the text after `FREE PPs:`, e.g. `217 (222208 megabytes)`. We call `match()` on that field to match `(` followed by some digits. We assume success here! Because the match started at the open parenthesis, when we extract the digits for the free Mb, we skip one past RSTART and subtract one from RLENGTH.

If you plan on using this script's output as part of another pipeline, consider adjusting the `printf` statement to output only the digits, without the "Mb available\n" portion.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/lsfs -c /opt/OpCon | awk -F: 'NR == 2 {split($2, fields, "/"); print fields[3]}'`
opcon
`LANG=C lslv opcon 2>/dev/null | awk '/VOLUME GROUP/ { print $6 }'`
datavg
`LANC=C /usr/sbin/lsvg datavg | awk -F: '/FREE PP/ {match($3, /\([[:digit:]]*/); print substr($3, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1)}'`
29696
`freefs /opt/OpCon`
We add 29696 Mb available on '/opt/OpCon'`

Many many thanks, i can't thank you enough. Very well explained script with awk part, the usage.
This will give my envy to try next time ksh script.
Is it important to take care about the LANG=C and Unix?

Comment: Happy to hear it helped! ksh is a good shell on AIX, although a purist would point out (and I've updated my post to reflect) that I haven't used any ksh-specific features, so plain /bin/sh would work here, too. I copied AIX's own scripts with `LANG=C` (note the one typo I had earlier with LANC=C that I just corrected); I believe the point there is to force `lslv` and `lsvg` to report in English so that the `awk` statements can find the text they're expecting. I would recommend keeping it for scripts, or unless you know that English is the only language in use.

Comment: Ok thank you for all the precious information, have a great day Jeff